# openssl s_client shows an incorrect certificate chain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, ssl-certificate-errors

On one of my servers belonging to a customer I "suddenly" cannot verify any public TLS certificates. All requests to "the public" fail on an invalid certificate. I can, however, verify certificates signed by the customer's CA.

```
martin@svuburhate12:~$ curl https://google.com
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I have a few VMs in the customer's datacenter, all I have is ssh access, I have no control over the networking surrounding it. Other servers of the customer are OK.

When I check the certificates that are actually sent back, there is something really weird going on. **Apparently, Google sends back its wildcard certificate and the issuer of that is the intermediate CA of the customer.** Verifying this chain understandably fails.

```bash
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 99 -connect google.com:443 -servername google.com
verify depth is 99
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = local, O = Customer, CN = Redacted Root CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:1
depth=2 C = local, O = Customer, CN = Redacted Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = FI, O = Customer, CN = Redacted Online CA1
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.google.com
verify return:1
---

Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.google.com
   i:C = FI, O = Customer, CN = Redacted Online CA1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

 1 s:C = FI, O = Customer, CN = Redacted Online CA1
   i:C = local, O = Customer, CN = Redacted Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

 2 s:C = local, O = Customer, CN = Redacted Root CA
   i:C = local, O = Customer, CN = Redacted Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

---

Server certificate
subject=CN = *.google.com

issuer=C = FI, O = Customer, CN = Redacted Online CA1

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5654 bytes and written 428 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

The way I understand `openssl s_client` is that what I am seeing is really what is coming in through the network. Is that correct?

What does this mean? Is there something in the networking "around the server" that injects invalid certificates into the response *somehow*?

Comment: Has the company recently installed a TLS/SSL Inspection service, such as ZScaler?

Comment: I sent them a question about whether something changed recently. I'll include this there explicitly.

Comment: There is likely some corporate security solution installed which inspects the traffic. All major vendors of security products can do this. The relevant proxy CA needs to be installed as trusted

Comment: Sounds like it, thanks for the info. I still want to confirm with the customer if this is true, before I start trusting some CA

Comment: To your side Q, _in this case_ `s_client` shows only the certs received. There are other cases where `s_client` finds an alternate path during validation, and the `-showcerts` display (`s: i: <PEM block>`) is the chain as received while the callback log (`depth=# subj / verify error: / verify return:`) is the chain validated. For example LetsEncrypt is still by default giving out a chain that bridges to an expired DST/Identrust root (though they've announced they will finally stop next year) so the chain received shows that bridge while the chain validated shows the up-to-date ISRG root.